# IE6, lightboxes, and IFRAMEs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-6

I have a site, which upon clicking an image a lightbox pops up (eg http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/).

Our customer still has some machines which run IE6 (upgrading is unfortunately beyond our control), so in order to block out some `SELECT` elements, I have used the old `IFRAME` shim trick (as described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/08/09/how-to-put-a-div-over-a-select-in-ie.aspx).

However, I have the following problems:

- The lightbox doesn't appear until the mouse is not longer hovering over the page - moving the mosue to a different window, or even just to the scroll bar causes it to appear;
- While the mouse is over the page, the following doesn't happen:

  - Any jQuery animations related to the lightbox stop (or to be more precise, the animation continues in the background, only to have finished upon mouse out);
  - Animated `gif`s inside the lightbox stop running until mouse out;
  - Javascript in general stops until mouse out.

Everything seems to run fine in our other supported browsers (IE7 and FF).

Unfortunately I don't have a link to show you these effects, but hopefully I have explained myself enough for somebody to help (which will be very gratefully received)!

**Edit:**

Forgot to say, I know this is related to the `IFRAME`, as removing it causes the javascript to run fine, but obviously the ugly `SELECT` boxes bleed through the top `DIV`.

Comment: You'll at least have to show us your code, you can embed it in your question.

Comment: Posting some code is a bit difficult, as it's on another machine isolated from the web, with no easy way of transferring between. Just wondering really if this is a well-known effect.

Comment: It sounds like you have something heavy running in a mousemove or mouseover event handler that's blocking animations, animated GIFs, etc. As Marcel Korpel says, we'll need to see some code to know what's happening.

Comment: If you were to move that comment to an answer, Jeffery, you'd get the points, as that was exactly the problem! ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have something heavy running in a mousemove or mouseover event handler that's blocking animations, animated GIFs, etc.